# Как записать результат умножения данных из трех массивов размеров в один массив объемов?

Tags: java, массивы

Задание из книги *ООП в языке Java. Сборник заданий и тематических примеров*:

- Инициализировать массивы `a`, `b`, `c` из `n` чисел случайными
  значениями.
- Понимая, что `a[i]`, `b[i]`, `c[i]` обозначают длины
  ребер кирпичей, определить кирпич с максимальным объемом.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;

public class Kirpich {        

    static int[] generationArr(final int MAX, final int MIN, int n) {
        int[] array = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (MAX - MIN) + MAX);
        }
        return array;
    }
        
    static int[] volume(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c, int n) {

        int[] arrs = new int[n];

        for( int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
            //int a1 = a[i];
            //int b1 = b[i];
            //int c1 = c[i];
            for(int j = 0; j < arrs.length; j++) {
                arrs = (a[i]*b[i]*c[i]);
            }
        }
        return arrs;
    }
}
```

Как записать результат умножения в массив, чтобы потом найти индекс максимального?

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Умножить и записать в массив, что тут непонятного?

Comment: Вообще-то массив объёмов не нужен, при расчете очередного объема сравнивайте его с максимумом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что в методе `volume` вы пытаетесь создать массив со значениями *объёмов* кирпичей, но в данном случае *вложенный* цикл не нужен, достаточно одного цикла.

```java
static int[] volume(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c, int n) {

    int[] v = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        int ai = i < a.length ? a[i] : 0;
        int bi = i < b.length ? b[i] : 0;
        int ci = i < c.length ? c[i] : 0;

        v[i] = ai * bi * ci;
    }
    return v;
}
```

---

Вложенный цикл можно было бы использовать, если бы вычислялись объёмы M кирпичей для некоторого количества размеров.

Благодаря использованию vararg-синтаксиса `...`, можно вычислять объёмы N-мерных кирпичей :)

```java
static int[] volumes(int m, int[] ... sizes) {
    int[] v = new int[m]; // количество кирпичей
    
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int vi = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < sizes.length; j++) {
            vi *= sizes[j][i];
        }
        v[i] = vi;
    }
    return v;
}
```

---

В принципе, в задании не указано, что *обязательно* требуется создавать массив с объёмами кирпичей, поэтому, как верно указал @MBo в комментарии, достаточно найти индекс максимального объёма:

```java
static int indexOfMaxVolume(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c, int n) {

    if (n <= 0 || a.length < 1 || b.length < 1 || c.length < 1) {
        return -1;
    }

    int maxIndex = 0;
    int m = Math.min(Math.min(n, a.length), Math.min(b.length, c.length));
    for (int i = 1; i < m; i++) {
        if (a[i] * b[i] * c[i] > a[maxIndex] * b[maxIndex] * c[maxIndex]) {
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}
```